# How gazebo communicates with ardupilot SITL?

Tags: simulation, robotics

I would like to know that how iris+ drone model is run with motor inputs. What I mean is, I would like to know that how much thrust is generated and how it is applied to/from a rotor. firmware computes the input as thrust in the range 0-1 and converts into PWM signal I am using `F=k_t * w^2` and `T=k_d * w^2` formulas to compute force and torque generated by a rotor were `k_t and k_d` are known for the particular rotor which I don't know for iris+ quadrotor.

I need to know the amount of force applied to the quad in gazebo and inertia matrix for complete model and how to convert that thrust and torque to a `rpm^2`.

Can somebody clarify these issues for me?

Comment: How does one apply ***trust*** to a rotor?

Comment: You do mean 'thrust' right?

Comment: Come on guys it is a typo, it is indeed thrust :D My autocomplete option has trolled me :p